# Filtering in a Dictionary with arabic letters is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

[image][image]Trying to Filter inside a dictionary for a similar key written in Arabic letters .

Example :

```
public static string MyCategoryTypeName= "الجيش";

  public static Dictionary<int, string> StaticNames = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                {الجيش" ,1"},
                {الأمن العام" ,2"},
                {أمن الدولة",3 "},
                {الجمارك" ,4 "}
            };
 int selectedID = (from x in StaticNames where x.Key.Contains(MyCategoryTypeName) select x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Original arabic string replaced with `<arabic_string>`, because StackOverflow's code formatting doesn't seem compatible with arabic.*

I have tried Linq, I have tried to loop through each object and check the identical name, but nothing is not working

```
int selectedID = (from x in StaticNames where x.Value.ToString().Contains(MyCategoryTypeName) select x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

selectedID = 0;
foreach (var item in StaticNames)
{
    if (item.Key.Contains(person.CategoryTypeName))
    {
        selectedID = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
    }
}
```

One of these should return an integer (1 to 4). 
It always return 0 (which is the default value  for an integer).

Comment: `int selectedID = (from x in StaticNames where x.Value.ToString().Contains(MyCategoryTypeName) select x.Key).FirstOrDefault();` Works fine for me (I had to make some changes, since your code didn't compile). https://dotnetfiddle.net/YS5G6e

Comment: I can't confirm the behaviour of your last code sample, since it doesn't compile. But if (somehow?) this last code sample isn't working for you (once you get it to compile), it is probably not working since the string is not actually contained in the other string.

Comment: Any luck testing my idea @markdibe?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `x.Value` use `x.key` and it should work

```
  int selectedID = (from x in StaticNames where 
  x.Key.Contains("الجيش") select x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

You are matching values not key your key contains the string you want to match.

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue is simply that, but it wasn't obvious given that the arabic strings are kinda messing the code format.

Comment: @Kilazur yes, I just realized that too.

Comment: no it is not the answer i have mentioned  that after pasting the dictionary here it inverts them , i will add a screen shot for the code

Comment: @markdibe after editing your code you are still comparing the intergers, try to understand key value pairs you will get your answer. You just need to compare the arabic strings

Comment: @markdibe it's been understood that the code was messing up. Your keys are the first elements, the integers; and your values are the second elements, the strings. So you should indeed test the values and not the keys, since you're trying to RETRIEVE the keys from the values.

Comment: let me test again and ill reply , just uno momento

Comment: @markdibe edit your question, add your code you tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630817/just-code    I did please look at the images

Comment: @markdibe I want to know what is in there in staticnames

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630817/just-code 

just see the image man , the names are clear as f... (lol)

Comment: @markdibe, remember this thing, you need to compare string values, when you are writing correct code you will not have to write `tostring`. now remove tostring check if there is any compilation errors then revert back to x.key or values whichever is working. now when this works, you need to make sure the contains string actually exists in string. there is no magic here. you are just comparing what you are expecting to.

Comment: @Justcode
I have tried without (toString()) .
still not working
i know that there is no magic here

Comment: @markdibe If you want to reply to users on Stack Overflow, use the @-mention like I did with the username. By using the link to their profile as you did they won't get notified of your reply.

Answer (score 0):

this code must work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int selectedID = (from x in StaticNames where x.Key.Contains(MyCategoryTypeName) select x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(selectedID);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static string MyCategoryTypeName = "الجيش";
    public static Dictionary<string, int> StaticNames = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"الجيش" ,1},
            {"الأمن العام" ,2},
            {"أمن الدولة",3 },
            {"الجمارك" ,4 }
        };
```

test this code in console then use in your project